# Library import option wont show and when i import the library shows Unused import statement

Tags: java, android

Hello im coding with java in android and i have this code:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
**setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
if(getSupportActionBar() != null){
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeAsUpEnabled(true);**
}
```

the code inside the ** requires this library to be imported but first the suggestion to import the libary wont show and when i import it myself  it says  **Unused import statement**

this is the import code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

the weird part is that the same method is been used in the same project but only in this class wont work.

I also tried to do this method but makes error when its on run time

```
AppCompatActivity app = new AppCompatActivity();
app.setSupportActionBar(toolbar); //error here when execute
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it the solution was add **AppCompatActivity** on

```
public class X extends AppCompatActivity ....
```